# How to skip the test classes in OSGI integration test?

Tags: java, junit, osgi, osgi-bundle, osgi-fragment

In the junit we can use the Assume.assumeTrue(false) to skip the execution of the test cases.

`@BeforeClass public static void beforeClass() { Assume.assumeTrue(booleanCondition()); }`

But in OSGI integration i am not able to use the assumeTrue.
So how can i skip the test class execution based on the condition in osgi integration tests.